# How to make my Discord Bot reply with a mention?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

For example I want that someone sends in: "make my friend @FreezyGuy"
Then my bot responds that: "making @FreezyGuy you friend is in progress..."

I even want my bot go back after 10 seconds and edit the message to: "@FreezyGuy is your friend now!"

If you can help with this second part you are awesome, but if you can with the mention that would be great as well.

```js
client.on("message", function(message) {
  if (message.content === `make my friend` @mention) 
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    
    else if(message.content === `make my friend` @mention){
        message.channel.send(`making @mention your friend is in progress...`)
}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know how setTimeout works? I have this function that I use with my discord bot when getting mod applications.

```
    function waitmessage() {
        setTimeout(function(){msg.channel.send('This message waited 1 second to send!')}, 1000)
    }
```

The time is measured in milliseconds, so 1000 = 1 second.
Once you have this function set up, you need to call the function later on in your code whenever you want to have this message to wait, for example:

```
msg.channel.send(waitmessage)
```

Which would make the bot start the function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct way to @ a user is by using `<@[userID]>`

For example `Hello <@1234567890> to the server`

As seen here:
https://discordjs.guide/miscellaneous/parsing-mention-arguments.html#implementation